# Javascript order object properties based on defined value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a two pieces of data I am working with to ultimately generate an HTML table.

**Data:** This is the core data that would come from a database call.

**UserColumns:** This defines which order the table columns will be in. The `fieldSource` in this object will align with the key names in the `data` object.

```
// Define the core data we will be working with. Assumed this comes from a database,
var data = [{
    FirstName: 'Joe',
    LastName: 'Jones',
    Age: 21,
    Location: 'Arizona',
    Color: 'Red', // Not defined in the column structure, therefore is not included in output
    Order: 1
  },
  {
    FirstName: 'Tim',
    LastName: 'Bob',
    Age: 25,
    Location: 'California',
    Color: 'Blue',
    Order: 3
  },
  {
    FirstName: 'Sally',
    LastName: 'Smith',
    Age: 29,
    Location: 'Florida',
    Color: 'Green',
    Order: 2
  }
];

// Defines the columns the user wants to include in their table output as well as their order
var userColumns = [{
    FieldID: 1,
    FieldSource: 'FirstName',
    FieldName: 'First Name',
    Order: 2
  },
  {
    FieldID: 2,
    FieldSource: 'LastName',
    FieldName: 'Last Name',
    Order: 1
  },
  {
    FieldID: 3,
    FieldSource: 'Age',
    FieldName: 'Age',
    Order: 4
  },
  {
    FieldID: 4,
    FieldSource: 'Location',
    FieldName: 'Location',
    Order: 3
  }
];

/*
    Loop over the data and order the content in the desired column order.
*/
function generateTableRows() {

  let output = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    // Need to re-order the object keys based on the "User Columns".
    // This also needs to ensure the the table rows are in the correct order based on the "Order" property
    console.log(data[j]);
  }

}
```

In the example code above, the `keys` in `data` need to be re-ordered to match the order defined in the `userColumns` object.

End goal here is that the user will see the table of data in their desired view (columns in the defined order).

How can I go about putting the keys in a specific order and will they remain that way in the object or can they change?

I need to essentially take an object of data and then output re-arrange it so that its in the user defined order when it comes time to render a table.

Here is a fiddle of the full task at hand I am trying to workout: https://jsfiddle.net/os48s1ne/

Comment: Object properties don't have any order.

Comment: @Barmar - Correct, which is why I am trying to figure out how to structure this so that I can define one (through an array for example or some other means).

Comment: Sort `userColumns` by the `Order` property. Then loop through `userColumns` and access the corresponding property of `data[j]`.

Comment: The answer below is solid, but if you want to preserve order you should consider assigning the values generated by that code in the answer to a `Set()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the `userColumns` property, then loop through it and use the `FieldSource` properties to access the corresponding properties in the data.

```js
/*
    Loop over the data and order the content in the desired column order.
*/
function generateTableRows() {
  userColumns.sort((a, b) => a.Order - b.Order);
  let output = data.map(d => userColumns.map(({
    FieldSource,
    FieldName
  }) => `${FieldName} = ${d[FieldSource]}`).join(', '));
  console.log(output);
}

// Define the core data we will be working with. Assumed this comes from a database,
var data = [{
    FirstName: 'Joe',
    LastName: 'Jones',
    Age: 21,
    Location: 'Arizona',
    Color: 'Red', // Not defined in the column structure, therefore is not included in output
    Order: 1
  },
  {
    FirstName: 'Tim',
    LastName: 'Bob',
    Age: 25,
    Location: 'California',
    Color: 'Blue',
    Order: 3
  },
  {
    FirstName: 'Sally',
    LastName: 'Smith',
    Age: 29,
    Location: 'Florida',
    Color: 'Green',
    Order: 2
  }
];

// Defines the columns the user wants to include in their table output as well as their order
var userColumns = [{
    FieldID: 1,
    FieldSource: 'FirstName',
    FieldName: 'First Name',
    Order: 2
  },
  {
    FieldID: 2,
    FieldSource: 'LastName',
    FieldName: 'Last Name',
    Order: 1
  },
  {
    FieldID: 3,
    FieldSource: 'Age',
    FieldName: 'Age',
    Order: 4
  },
  {
    FieldID: 4,
    FieldSource: 'Location',
    FieldName: 'Location',
    Order: 3
  }
];



generateTableRows();
```

Comment: Is it possible to include the data with the final array? For example: `var output = [{
    data: {
        FirstName: 'Joe',
        LastName: 'Jones',
        Age: 21,
        Location: 'Arizona',
        Color: 'Red',
        Order: 1
    },
    newStuff: [Jones, Joe, Arizona, 21]
}]`

Comment: This function is used to generate table rows. I need to hardcode the first `td` in my table to contain a specific datapoint from the result. The issue is that since the final output is just the array, I can't call the datapoint I need by the property name `data.Color` for example. Here is the final output I am trying to get https://jsfiddle.net/f3ubeho2/

Comment: `let output = data.map(d => ({ data: d, newStuff: userColumns.map(({
    FieldSource,
    FieldName
  }) => `${d[FieldSource]}`)}));`